# Xcode will not compile my whole code

Tags: xcode

I just installed Xcode on my new iMac, and for some reason it will not run my entire code. My little brother was missing around with the setting and I don't know if that is the cause. Is there a way to reset Xcode to a default setting? I've already deleted it and reinstalled it but its still doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

He either messed up your project or code, and caused a build error.  The only thing Xcode can do is set the project's treatment of warnings as errors.  On the left pane select the tab with the warning sign on it (triangle with a ! on it).  It should tell you on that list why it didn't compile.

Try to make a new project and see if that one compiles.  Then you know it is only your code.  You're going to have to learn how to do debugging like this so your little brother is helping you.